# How do I get the number of lines changed for specific types of files by authors in a git repository?

Tags: git

I've found several scripts here to get the total number of lines changed by authors in a git repository.

(this is the one I've been using.  Further down the answers is a small ruby script:  [How to count total lines changed by a specific author in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository))

But in my case I dont want to count the lines of code in .xml files.  I only want to count the number of lines changed in .cs files.

My expected output would be something like:

Author1 5342 lines
Author2 3843 lines
.
.
.

I'm on a windows machine, so ruby scirpts or powershell scripts are welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2788077/498699

Comment: Can you please add to your question links to answers that provide the scripts that you mentioned so that we have an idea of what you're looking for and what similar solutions already exist?