# Finding the most frequent committer to a specific file

Tags: git

Given a specific file in a git repository, how would I go about finding who are the most frequent committers in that file?

Comment: what your 'frequent' means here? the times who commit more than any others or the lines?

Comment: Good question. Could you post both?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [git shortlog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog) for this:

```
git shortlog -sn -- path/to/file
```

This will print out a list of authors for the path, ordered and prefixed by the commit count.

Usually, this command is used to get a quick summary of changes, e.g. to generate a changelog. With `-s`, the change summaries are suppressed, leaving only the author names. And paired with `-n`, the output is sorted by the the commit count.

Of course, instead of the path to a file, you can also use a path to a directory to look at the commits to that path instead. And if you leave off the path completely, `git shortlog -sn` gives you statistics for the whole repository.

Comment: Great answer, better than mine :) but you probably need additional `--follow` to detect renames.

Comment: Thank you! How about number of lines changed?

Comment: @LeoNatan That’s a different question, and a bit more complicated; you could parse the output from `git log --shortstat` similar to Patryk’s answer. But check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787253/show-number-of-changed-lines-per-author-in-git) for more ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You can short output according to the number of commits per user.

```
$ git shortlog -sen <file/path>

Here,
-s for commit summary
-e for email
-n short by number instead of alphabetic order  

// more info
$ git shortlog --help
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git log --follow <file> | grep "Author: " | sort | uniq -c | sort
```

Some explanation:

`git log --follow <file>` - limit log to specific file, follow through all renames of this file

`grep "Author:" | sort` - take only lines with Authors and group authors together

`uniq -c | sort` - count authors in groups and sort it again, so most frequent one is in first line

:)

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --format="%cn" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Get the committer name of each commit, group and count, sort in descending order.