# How to find who contributed most lines of code on a specific file

Tags: git

I set reviewers for my pull requests very often. To choose the reviewer, I want to find the person who contributed most to the changed files.

I found a similar approach [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014063/4843237) which summarizes by commit count per user:

`git shortlog -sn -- path/to/file`

but I'm more interested in finding a summary on existing lines of code. what's the best way to do that?

Comment: git tracks everything using commits only, I don't think there is another way

Comment: This metric will be horribly flawed in some contexts, use it for fun only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT contribution per author (lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449075/git-contribution-per-author-lines)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+count+contribution+by+author