# Is there a way to get git statistics for changed/added/removed lines per user for a specific filetype?

Tags: git, version-control, statistics, git-status

I was wondering if there is a way to get git statistics for changed/added/removed lines per user for a specific filetype? i.e.: User A added 1.000.000 lines and removed 800.000. Is there a way to determine if the changes took place in files with i.e. .py extension?

Kind regards!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788077/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+count+changed+lines+author+type

Comment: You do have to do some manual tweaking, as in the sub-answers. You must find the commits by that author, then filter down to the desired file suffixes. Note that `git show --stat $hash -- '**/*.py'` should do the job pretty directly for each commit.