# Git: How to measure the amount of code changed in a period of time?

Tags: git

I'm looking for a command to execute against my git repo to discover the amount of code changed in a certain period of time.

I want to know how much code was changed since day 'X'. I don't really care about the percentage of code changed by each author.

Comment: Can you defined your metric? What does "how much" means? LOC?

Comment: Lines of Code would be a good metric.

Comment: almost - it needs a tweak to work for this question, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up the excellent answer Gabriele found, the exact command you need is:

```
git log --since=31/12/2012 --numstat --pretty="%H" | awk '
    NF==3 {plus+=$1; minus+=$2;}
    END   {printf("+%d, -%d\n", plus, minus)}'
```

(yes, you can paste that onto a single line, but the answer's more readable like this)

The key difference is the *in a certain period of time* requirement, handled by the `--since` argument.

Comment: Date would have been more useful with the days or months component greater than 12 to illustrate the format.

Comment: Fair point. For reference, the format used is `DD/MM/YYYY`, and `YYYY-MM-DD` also works.

Comment: Don't you need the `--no-merges` flag in the `git log` to avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `--stat` option of `git diff`.

For instance

```
git diff --stat HEAD HEAD~1
```

will tell you what changed from the last commit, but I think what's closest to your request is the command

```
git diff --shortstat HEAD HEAD~1
```

which will output something like

```
524 files changed, 1230 insertions(+), 92280 deletions(-)
```

**EDIT**

Actually I found this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528129/846273) that addresses the same issue much better that I can do.

Comment: this only outputs the no of lines added and deleted, but it there can be modified line too,. Modify means, in *old commit* `This is me` line is changed to `this is me` in the new commit. Is there a way to get the no of lines modified in a repo between commits

Answer (score 1):

As a less awksome alternative:

```
REV=$(git rev-list -n1 --before="1 month ago" master)
git diff --shortstat $REV..master
```

The "before" date can of course be a more standard representation of time as well.