# How to determine the unique number of changed lines in Git

Tags: java, git, jenkins, github, gitlab

Executing the following gives me the differences in line count between local changes and the remote versions of the file:

```
git diff --shortstat C:\dev\Sprint7 origin/master:C:\dev\Sprint7
```

Example result:

```
18 files changed, 11 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
```

Please, how do I calculate the total number of unique changed lines?

For instance, if line 5 of Login.jsp file is deleted and same line 5 is replace by another line (or string) (i.e. deletion and insertion is done on line 5), I want this to be counted as 1 changed line.

Can I get that count from the command above by summing the insertions and deletions?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No you can't. You could remove line 5 and add line 8 and they could be totally unrelated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the number of lines changed between two commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528111/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-lines-changed-between-two-commits-in-git)

Comment: Daniel, I appreciate your comment, but you were stating the obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am pasting a small shell script. Simply give the `git diff` command as input and rest will take care by the script itself.

```
#echo "Input Command : $1"
TOTAL_CHANGES_WITH_FILES="$($1 | grep '^+' | wc -l)"
TOTAL_CHANGED_FILES="$($1 | grep '^+++' | wc -l)"
RESULT=`expr ${TOTAL_CHANGES_WITH_FILES} - ${TOTAL_CHANGED_FILES}`
#echo "Total Changed Lines: ${RESULT}"
echo "${RESULT}"
```

save this code to file `changed_lines.sh` and run this file using command 
`sh changed_lines.sh "git diff HEAD"`. Replace `"git diff HEAD"` with the `git diff C:\dev\Sprint7 origin/master:C:\dev\Sprint7` as per your config. This will simply print the no. of lines that changed. If anything wrong. please feel free to comment. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks SV, I love the bash solution, but it is giving no of lines changes = insertions e.g. git diff --shortstat C:\dev\Sprint7 origin/master:C:\dev\Sprint7 gives 2 files changed, 48 insertions(+), 45 deletions(-). Your solution displays 48. Does that mean deletions is not taken into consideration? Also, how do I enhance the script to give the lines changed per file type or extenstion?

Comment: But mentioned in your question that you want only the `unique changed lines`. `For instance, if line 5 of Login.jsp file is deleted and same line 5 is replace by another line (or string) (i.e. deletion and insertion is done on line 5), I want this to be counted as 1 changed line.` So that's why my solution is like that.

Comment: So you want me to count the removed lines also? Exception case is if the same line is edited (+, - consecutively represents 1), I have to count it as one. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Goodday SV and thanks. A changed line inc delete, insert and updated.I v 2 usecases: (1). determine no of changed lines in a remote repo per file type. e.g. JSP,JS,Java,XML,XLSM. No local vs remote diff required, just remote git query. (2) no of changes per file type, ur solution is close, but we need to specify a root folder and file type for recursive git query. ATM, My workaround is e.g. for JSP > git diff --shortstat C:\[path-to-jsp] origin/master:C:\[path-to-jsp] . Which means having multiple hard coded path to known folders.Shell solution is good, but i'm happy w git cmds too. Thanks SV.

Comment: I am trying to apply the following to the script but no joy yet: shell globbing syntax (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/use-grep-exclude-include-syntax-to-not-grep-through-certain-files) :

grep pattern -r --include=\*.{jsp,java} rootdir