# Showing the total changed words in a git tracked file relative to a specific date

Tags: git

**Question:** In git, how does see the difference between the current state of a file and the most recent commit before a specific timestamp (i.e.: yesterday at 2pm)? I'm specifically interested in getting the total changed words (similar to the total changed lines lines +/-).

**Use case.** The use case I'm after is being able to track how much writing progress I've made relative to a date. In writing, the unit of progress is typically "words changed" as opposed to "lines changed" (other posts on StackOverflow cover lines changed, but not words changed).

**Example.** So for example, if I've added 200 words to file.txt and deleted 100 words since yesterday at 2pm, I'd like the result of this command to be something like "+200/-100".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the number of lines changed between two commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528111/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-lines-changed-between-two-commits-in-git)

Comment: @phd: That post discusses getting "number of lines changed"; my post discusses "total changed words".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't track words, only lines. You can still get the difference in the number of words in the file between two commits, with a bit of work, but there's no easy way (as far as I know) to get the number of words added and removed.

If you want to compare the number of words in a file as it was yesterday and as it is now, you can use the following Bash script (pass the filename as the first argument):

```sh
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    echo "pass a file to compare"
    exit 1
fi
orig_branch="$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)"
if [[ -z "$orig_branch" ]]; then  # detached HEAD
    orig_branch="$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
fi
words_now=$(wc -w "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1)
git checkout '@{yesterday}'
words_then=$(wc -w "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1)
printf '%+d\n' $((words_now - words_then))  # prints something like "+10" or "-42"
git checkout "$orig_branch"
```

NB: if your working directory is dirty when you run this, you might have problems. It's probably a good idea to `git stash save` your changes beforehand, and `git stash pop` them afterwards.

To get an added/removed count like Git will give you for lines, I guess you could probably [split the file you're comparing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342584/226269) into one word per line, then diff the two files.

Comment: `wc -w` spits out a number and a filename, which is causing this script to error. Do you know to fix this? Also: I'm assuing you should checkout your previous branch at the end of this script.

Comment: oops, that's what I get for not testing my answers before I post them :P I've updated the answer to fix that. Checking out the previous branch afterwards is harder than it sounds, but I've added that too.