# Way to get a detailed info of line changes in commit from git (ie line 3 removed, line 4 became line 3)

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out the best way to track the ways the lines in a given text file change from commit to commit, in hopes that I can give them unique IDs (which is a whole other hullaballoo for another time)...

Ideally, I'm looking for some sort of data equal to the visual representation in the change log view -- where I can easily see, ok:

- line 1 -> line 1
- line 2 -> line 2
- _____ -> line 3 NEW
- line 3 -> _______REMOVED
- line 4 -> _______REMOVED
- line 5 -> becomes line 4

etc etc

The change log visually contains what I'm looking for:

[image: The change log visually contains what I'm looking for in this clip...]

My knowledge of git & sourcecontrol is functional but this is definitely pulling me into the deep end and I haven't found anyone looking for this exact same thing (which makes me worry I might be taking the wrong approach but...)

What I've tried so far is git diff (--stat, --numstat) but have only found the amount of lines added and removed, as per [this question about finding the # of lines changed with diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528111/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-lines-changed-between-two-commits-in-git)
Somehow that led me to leaning about patch files, and seeing if I can pull the info out of there, which might be do-able if i write a thing to process and calculate the line changes (which might be what I end up having to do...)

Is there is a command line that goes to this level of change log detail? I can conceptualize how I could calculate this by iterating through each patch line, checking if an addition or subtraction has been made, and applying that to the count of the line, but first i thought i'd make sure it isn't doable with command.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you are trying to achieve.  I used perforce for many years before using git.  One command I have not found a full substitute for is, `p4 annotate -a ...`.  I have not found a way to find deleted lines using `git blame ...`.

That said, I have made good use of `git log -p ...` to search through the full text of several patches to find changes to specific lines of code.