# How to find the total LOC changed or added in a release in GITLAB

Tags: git, gitlab

**Scenario:**
A code base was migrated from SVN to GITLAB, including its history (History of code changes done in SVN). After migrating to GITLAB, code changes were done for a certain time period for a release.

Therefore, in this release, there are code changes in SVN and also in GITLAB and GITLAB contains all the history of code changes in GITLAB and also in SVN.

**Objective:**
Find out the total number of code changes done in this release.

For example in svn, by the help of the below command, we get the modified code statements with a prefix +. From that output, we can find out the number of LOC modified.

```
svn diff -r <RevisionNumberToStartFrom>:<RevisionNumberToEndWith> <SVN_URL>
```

Output:

```
-int a = 0;
-int b = 0;
-int c = 1;
+int a1 = 2;
+int b1 = 3;
+int c1 = 4;
```

Any help to find out the GITLAB commands that can give us an ouput like the above format will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the number of lines changed between two commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528111/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-lines-changed-between-two-commits-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+count+changed+lines