# How can I calculate the number of lines added and modified from First commit(initial commit) to Last commit in git?

Tags: git, github

How can I calculate the number of lines added and modified from First 
commit(initial commit) to Last commit in git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the number of lines changed between two commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528111/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-lines-changed-between-two-commits-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+count+changed+lines

Comment: @php - the question you referred is about 2 commit, and this question specifically is  about first commit and last commit. Hence this is not duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Either of below commands can be used, stats will be same

1) display stats with count of changed file, insertion count and deletion count

`git diff  $(git log  --pretty=format:"%h" | tail -1) --shortstat`

2) display only count of changed and newly added line count, but does not consider deleted line count

`git diff  $(git log  --pretty=format:"%h" | tail -1)  | grep '^+' | grep -v +++ |  wc -l`