# Getting LOC +/- over a 24-hour period for a given user

Tags: git, github

For a given contributor, how can one (across all branches of a git repo) see  LOC +/- over the previous 24 hours across all commits?

In other words, how can git be converted into a LOC accountability tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
 git log --numstat --pretty="%H" --author="<some author name>" --since="one day" | awk 'NF==3 {plus+=$1; minus+=$2} END {printf("+%d, -%d\n", plus, minus)}'
```

This uses numstats from all commits made by a given author last day (`--since="one day"` limits the result to last 24 hours, could be combined with `--until` and changed to absolute dates) and awk for summing the stats and printing the result.

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528129/1157272, but with another limiting)