# Get number of changed lines of code per commit in Git

Tags: git

I would like to get number of lines of code changed per commit. Is it possible?

I am trying the following command but it is giving numstat details for commits before my specified commit as well.

```
git log --numstat [commit hash]
```

Comment: What is the exact output you want?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I basically want something like this
Commit Date, Commit Hash, Subject/Message, No. of files modified, Lines Added, Lines Removed

Comment: 2019-08-01, 3002fd1f2, '#11063 commit message',   1, 10, 13

Comment: This links is exactly what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528111/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-lines-changed-between-two-commits-in-git/2528129

Comment: Thank you for that but it seems like I need to have 2 commits.

Comment: @artsylar It only makes sense to speak of lines changed in going from one commit to another.  So, in your case, "one" commit means that you started at some previous commit, did a delta, and then ended up in some other commit.

Comment: I was able to output something like this actually
2019-08-01, 3002fd1f2, '#11063 Update xxxxxxxx, xxxxx',   1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 13 deletions(-)

Comment: But I don't need "file changed", "insertions(+)" and "deletions(-) texts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the number of lines changed between two commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528111/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-lines-changed-between-two-commits-in-git)