# How to count the total lines added & deleted in a Git repository for one year

Tags: git

How to count the total lines added & deleted in a Git repository for one year(January to December 2020).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+count+changed+lines

Comment: Esp. [`git diff --shortstat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41307958/7976758). To name commits by date instead of SHA1/refs use [`HEAD@{2020-01-01}` syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtltdategtemegemmasteryesterdayememHEAD5minutesagoem)